# Get rows inserted since last check?

Tags: sql, database, cqrs

I am implementing a [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) pattern where one or more processes are inserting records into the database and one or more processes are pulling them at a difference pace.

I'd like consumer processes to poll the database for new records that were inserted since last check, but I'm not sure how to (safely) implement this.

You can assume that rows will not change once they are inserted. It seems it isn't enough for each row to have a unique id, and a timestamp indicating when it was inserted.

If I query for records with a timestamp greater than the last row I saw then I run into problems if multiple records were inserted at the same time (having the same timestamp).

If I query for records with an id greater than the last row I saw then I run into problems where concurrent transactions may commit IDs in non-increasing order (e.g. postgreSQL sessions allocate and cache sequence IDs ahead of time to improve performance).

Ideally, I am looking for a DBMS-agnostic solution and be able to consume data as close to real-time as possible. Any ideas?

**Clarification**: Each row should be consumed multiple times, once per consumer. Meaning, just because one consumer processes a row should not prevent other consumers from doing so. Each consumer will do something different with the same data.

Comment: Since you have multiple consumers, you either need a way for them to have a shared storage to be able to figure out what they have read and processed. One way of doing that is maintaining that on the source table by updating some column when being processed. If not possible to change the table structure, you can create a new table or have some other form of maintaining the records processed by each consumer such as in memory, a new table or some shared file.

Comment: @clinomaniac I clarified the question: each row should be consumed multiple times, once per consumer.

Comment: That makes things simpler since you don't need the consumers to figure out if each row has been processed. Now the only issue is the uniqueness for each consumer. If the time stamp is not unique enough, one very simple way is to always get the data which doesn't include the current (can be relative). This should help based on my assumption that you will not get an older time stamp in the data. When the consumer polls again, you'll get the last one. Basically what it means is that ignore the data that has come in during the last 10 seconds or so to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @clinomaniac As mentioned in the question: if two rows were committed at the same time, but you only read one of them in your last query then the next time you run the query you will miss the second row.

Comment: You get everything that was written 10s (or certain amount of time) ago. You can read more than one rows at once.

Comment: @clinomaniac Okay, but now my result contains some rows that I've already seen. So how do I differentiate between the rows that I've already seen and the ones that I haven't seeing as the resultset could be large?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165236/discussion-between-clinomaniac-and-gili).

Comment: Do you use sharding?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Not at this time, but how would that affect the answer?

Comment: @Gili yes. You must include every detail regarding the requirements.

Comment: I will give you an answer when I can

Comment: Unrelated, a Postgres session only caches sequence numbers if the sequence was created with a `cache` value `>1`. If you create the sequence with `cache 1` nothing will be cached

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of data coming in and might have multiple records for the last time stamp, you need a way to keep track of the data read. Here are a few different approaches with their pro and cons:

1. You can wait for the data to come in for a time stamp. You would do this by not reading the `MAX(timestamp)` so you would get all the data from the table except the last one for which the data might still be coming in.

Pro: Simple design

Con: Not real time processing

2. You can store the id's you have read each time for the last time stamp. When getting the data, you can use a query like `(timestamp = lasttimestamp and id not in (set of ids)) or timestamp > lasttimestamp)`

Pro: Almost real time

Con: Additional storage required

Comment: What if the server gets its time updated? For example, it may be set 1 second back in time.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu The question states "You can assume that rows will not change once they are inserted." If that wasn't true, you could add a database-set timestamp column indicating when the row was last updated. You would then select against this column instead of the user-set one.

Comment: @Gili you don't understand my comment. When the server will get its system time updated (i.e.by using NTP), the **new** rows will have timestamps in the **past**.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Right, that would be problematic. What do you recommend then? Ideally we want an ever-increasing time or version number that gets stamped alongside each row.

Comment: That wouldn't matter because the timestamp is still the same. We are not using server time for any computation. As long as the time stamps are maintained, it would not be an issue.

Comment: @clinomaniac and the timestamp from where do you think it is taken?

Comment: Your solution is very good if the OP has atomic clocks (like Google has)

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Assuming that NTP will roll you back in time at most X seconds where X is a small value, simply query all rows since `lastTimestamp - X` and rely on the set of already-seen-IDs to protect you against duplicates. This should scale a lot better than a serializable number generator.

Comment: And they are in the wrong sequence/order. See what OP has commented on my answer: `I am talking about the fact that sequences are not guaranteed to insert numbers in the same order that transactions are committed`

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I never stated that the returned rows had to come back in order. The only thing that matters is that we don't miss any new rows, nor that we return any duplicates. The quote you mentioned is not relevant once we allow our query to go back in time. If the query returns rows from 10 seconds earlier than what we think is the start of new rows, then exclude duplicates using a set of known IDs, then you have a 10 seconds safety window where NTP could have rolled you back in time or a transaction was left open for 10 seconds before committing.

Comment: Relaying on system time that can be changed by any process leads to a fragile system.

Comment: But if this is something that the OP accepts then your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't use sharding or similar:**

You can use *optimistic locking*.

For this you can create an `order` column, with an unique index on the records table (the Log). Before each insertion, the producer query the Log for the greatest `order`, it increments it and insert the next record with this `order`.

If a concurrency exception occurs (i.e. `Duplicate entry '12345' for key order`) then you retry the entire process (query, increment, insert).

**If you use sharding or similar:**

Then you will need an additional service/table that will generate a new, unique, always-increasing `order` integer every time it is asked to do so.

This has the disadvantage that there is another piece that must be managed, a single point of failure that must be highly-available.

*P.S.*

- "sharding or similar" means that you can't have unique indexes on the entire table because you use sharding or you write to multiple tables.
- you can't rely on the timestamps or anything that relates to physical time because the system time may be adjusted, by an automated service (NTP) or by an human operator.

Comment: Your `sequence` approach requires crippling performance. Read the section `Unexpected results might be obtained if a cache setting greater than one is used for a sequence object that will be used concurrently by multiple sessions.` in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: @Gili it is only a coincidence that it is named `sequence`, it is not a Postgresql SEQUENCE.

Comment: @Gili an unique index on an integer value on a non-sharded table is not "crippling". I use an unique index on my MongoDB Event Store implementation with millions of documents and it is blazing fast.

Comment: I'm not talking about a unique index. I am talking about the fact that sequences are not guaranteed to insert numbers in the same order that transactions are committed. Example: T1 inserts row 1 (pulls sequence #1). T2 inserts row 2 (pulls sequence #2). T2 commits before T1. Consumer sees sequence #2 is the latest. T1 inserts row 3 (pulls sequence #3). T1 commits. Now the database contains rows with sequence `2, 1, 3` and the consumer will skip over the row with sequence #1.

Comment: @Gili T2 does not pull #2 because #1 is not yet commited.

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html: `Because sequences are non-transactional, changes made by setval are not undone if the transaction rolls back`. Further, they mention above that `nextval` will return distinct results if two sessions pull concurrently.

Comment: @Gili my sequence is not a postgresql sequence.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean now. So producers are essentially sequential (non-concurrent).

Comment: I've edited my answer. Yes, they are *serialized* by using optimistic locking

Comment: You can not have global ordering without serialization or an absolute time reference. Look at Apache Kafka, they offer ordering only in a partition and writers to a partition are serialized.